# What is the difference between a final Class and a Record?

Tags: java, record, java-17, final-class

In simple words what is the difference between a **final class** and a **record** in Java 17?

In which case should I use a record?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Record** is an ***immutable class***, i.e. all its fields are `final`. *Records* are implicitly `final`, hence as well as regular *final class* `record` can't be *extended*.

There are a number of **restrictions** imposed on records ([*for more details, take a look at **JEP 395***](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395)).

Contrary to *normal classes*:

- it's forbidden to declare ***instance fields*** *explicitly* inside **records** (*and reminder: all fields are* `final`, *which is a very important distinction*);
- `extends` clause is not allowed with **records**, because every **record** implicitly *extends* abstract class [Record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html);
- **record** can't be declared with any of these modifiers: `abstract`, `sealed`, or `non-sealed` (as a consequence of being implicitly `final`);
- **records** can't declare *instance initializers* and *native methods*.

Records are meant to be ***"transparent carriers for immutable data"*** as *JEP 395* says.

They are designed to be *concise*, *default constructor*, *getters*, `hashCode/equals` and `toString()` will be generated by the compiler for you. So that inside a **record** you need to declare only your custom logic (*if any*) and record declaration can be literally a ***one-liner***.

*Records* differ a lot from regular *final classes*.

Also, apart from the peculiarities mentioned above, the mechanism of *serialization / deserialization* was reimplemented for **records**, so that *deserialization* doesn't bypass the constructor.

> In which case should I use a record?

In short, if your objects must be ***stateful***, or you need to ***extend*** a particular class, then you can't utilize `record` in such a case.

On the other hand, if your objects are meant just ***carry the data***, they are not intended to be modified or inherit from other classes, then it might be a good candidate to be implemented as a `record`.

Comment: All these statements are true, but none of them really capture the essence of what it means to be a record.  A record _gives up the ability to decouple its representation from its API_.  That is, a record is the class _derived from_ a specific tuple of representation -- it must have a constructor accepting that tuple, it must have accessors for each component, etc.  But it is not about "the compiler generates stuff for you" -- it's about "this is the class _defined by_ this slug of data."  The syntactic concision is a bonus.

Answer (score 14):

A `final` class is simply one that cannot be extended.  But that imposes no other constraints on the class; it can still have mutable fields, fully encapsulate its state, etc.

A `record` is a transparent carrier for a given tuple of state components, and is required to expose an API derived from its state description.  Records are therefore more heavily constrained, but in exchange for these constraints, you get a great deal of convenience (constructors, accessors, `Object` methods) as well as some semantic promises (e.g., that unpacking a record with its component accessors and repacking the results with the constructor gives you an `equals` object.)

Records also happen to be `final` classes, but this is a very small part of what it means to be a record.